# Download modules in python 2.7 and not 3.4

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have python 3.4 and 2.7 installed in my ubuntu. I have most of my required modules installed in python 3.4 but I want to install them in python 2.7 also. Whenever I try the normal installation commands, I get `Requirement already satisfied` due to the module already being installed in python 3.4. How can I install modules for python 2.7?

E.g.
When I tried `pip install numpy`

I got

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

I have also tried `pip2.7 install numpy` but I get the same problem/error as above. I have read in some other answers that maybe `PYTHONPATH` needs to be changed. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

With two versions of python installed, specify the specific version of pip on invocation. For example: `pip2.7 install numpy`

Comment: I tried that and it's coming `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
` but in the python shell when I type `import numpy` I get an `ImportError`. I also tried `import numpy as np` but same problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

Comment: Yes I have. It still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: I don't get an error for the above command. It's coming Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages but in the python shell when I type import numpy I get an ImportError. I also tried import numpy as np but same problem

Comment: @Sibi I meant could you please post the full text of the Import Error

Comment: 'root@srilatha-ThinkPad-T430s:/usr/lib/python2.7# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun  3 2015, 17:00:38) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named numpy
>>> 
'

Comment: try importing `sys` and outputting the value of `sys.path`. What do you get?

Comment: ['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Answer (score 0):

My pip --version has this return:

```
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

verify what's return. The default is:

use pip3 to python 3.4:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

and pip to python 2.7.

Try uninstall and use get-pip.py:
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/#id8

Comment: pip --version returned `pip 7.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip-7.0.3-py3.4.egg (python 3.4)`

Comment: try remove and install again:  sudo apt-get remove python-pip. Download get-pip.py (find use: To install pip, securely download get-pip.py.) And in cd/Downloads install: sudo python get-pip.py.